# How much Cantonese and Mandarin is in Everything Everywhere all at Once?

Tags: dialogue, subtitles, everything-everywhere-all-at-once

Can someone that doesn't speak Cantonese nor Mandarin get away with watching the movie without subtitles?

I ask because I am in a foreign country where the movie is shown in English but the subs are in the native language.

Comment: Significant parts of the movie are in non-English. In the online version I saw, the English subtitles to the non-English spoken parts are "burned in" the picture, so it would be entirely possible that the version shown in your country has the same, plus subtitles for those parts as well (of course it is possible the local subtitles obscure those burned-in ones). There is also a part where the entire dialog is done through on-screen titles in English (saying more would spoil that part of the movie).

Comment: FYI: "burned-in" is properly called "open captions" (as opposed to closed captions). Open vs closed distinguishes between captions that can be hidden vs captions that all viewers must see.

Answer (score 24):

For anyone wondering, I went to the cinema to watch it, and while I was able to follow and did enjoy it, it was incredibly frustrating not knowing what was being said for large portions of the film.

I regret watching it this way and wouldn't advise someone to go ahead in the same way.

Comment: I saw it last night, with you in mind. I would have advised against it. The main protagonists are bi-lingual to such a degree that they swap languages back & forth mid-sentence. You really would have no hope of keeping up. There's also no differentiation by language as to what could be considered throw-away chit-chat or highly plot-relevant content.